# Integrating Mopub Native Ads for iOS with SwipeView

Tags: twitter, ads, mopub

I am having troubles with integrating Mopub Native Ads for iOS with [SwipeView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView) which is used in my app.

I found [here](https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/ios/native) that it's possible to integrate native ads into UITableView or UICollectionView, but it there any suggestions how to integrate native ads with my SwipeView? Anyone had same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think moPub's SDK plays well other frameworks that modifies the original method (swizzling) as sometimes they fight over replacing the original selector with their own.